# WPML translate option not showing for custom post types

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, wpml

I have wpml configured on my website. For default posts it shows the translate options as you can see in the image below.

[image]

Bur for custom post type it is not showing the translate option.

[image]

I did google to find some solution and the posts says that register_post_type might have some issue.

My code:

```
// Register Custom Post Type
function werk_post_type() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'Post Types', 'Post Type General Name', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'werk', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Werk', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Werk', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'archives'              => __( 'Item Archives', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Item:', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All Items', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Item', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New Item', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Item', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'update_item'           => __( 'Update Item', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View Item', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search Item', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into item', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this item', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'items_list'            => __( 'Items list', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Items list navigation', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter items list', 'twentysixteen' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'werk', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'description'           => __( 'Post Type Description', 'twentysixteen' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields', 'page-attributes', ),
        'taxonomies'            => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,        
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'page',
    );
    register_post_type( 'werk', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'werk_post_type', 0 );
```

Can someone help me out by pointing out what might be the issue here. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When editing on of your work post type entries, at the bottom of the page you should have a box called **Multilingual Content Setup**, which contains a checkbox: **Make 'Work' translatable**. Check that checkbox and hit **Apply**. Then you should be able to create translations for each work entry.
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. You just saved my day.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help :)